# Приложение для заказа товаров

Tags: java, android, android-studio, архитектура, mobile-development

### Дано:

Реализовать программу заказа товаров. Как реализовать само приложение, знаю.

### Вопрос:

1. Как правильно реализовать оформление заказа?
2. Как и куда должно приходить оповещение о заказе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ф.И.О, адрес, номер телефона, электронная почта, товар(количество, качество, вид..), дополнительная информация
2. Оповещение должно приходить на электронную почту, и на номер телефона смской

Comment: Первый пункт понял, а по второму вопрос, я правильно понял что интентом нужно отправить письмо на почту? И как смс отправить? Ведь при отправки смс на номер деньги уйдут со счета заказчика или я не так понял вас?

Comment: @java Если приложение у заказчика, то смс отправлять не нужно, если у отправителя(для подтверждения заказа, то нужно), я имею ввиду :
пользователь заказал товар через форму под номером 1, в ответ на это ему должно от заказчика прийти подтверждение заказа под номером 2

Comment: К примеру у вас в телефоне есть это приложение, вы делаете заказ н товаров чтоб купить у меня, выбираете товары оформляете его, интентом надо будет отправить на почту сведения о купленных товарах, а на телефон как?

Comment: с помощью смс, есть разные бесплатные сервисы, погуглите

Comment: Понял сейчас посмотрю, спасибо большое